# How to access Model Data in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pushstate

I have two forms, consider Form1 and Form2, both are MVC forms only. These forms using two different view models as shown below :

```
public class Form1ViewModel
{
     //some public properties

     public string QueryString { get; set; }
}


public class Form2ViewModel
{
     //some public properties

     public string PreviousQueryString { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller Post Action I'm writing like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessForm1(Form1ViewModel form1Obj)
{
     //some logic goes here

     //I'm preparing Querystring from form1 data and appending to Form2 model like

     Form2ViewModel form2Obj=new Form2ViewModel();
     form2Obj.PreviousQueryString = form1Obj.QueryString;

     return View("Form2",form2Obj) ;
}
```

And in Form1, I'm submitting through Jquery Ajax as

```js
 frm.submit(function(ev) {
   var formData = frm.serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'ControllerName/ProcessForm1',
     data: formData,
     success: function(response) {
       //Here i need to read the PreviousQueryString and need to push to window.history.pushState()
     }
     error: function() {}
   });
 });
```

In the Ajax success, I need to read the PreviousQueryString from the response.

I knew how to do it client side(using pure JS) but it's my requirement.

How can I do it?

Comment: try '@Request.QueryString["PreviousQueryString "]'

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
public string ProcessForm1(Form1ViewModel form1Obj)
{
     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     Form2ViewModel form2Obj=new Form2ViewModel();
     form2Obj.PreviousQueryString = form1Obj.QueryString;
      return js.Serialize(form2Obj);
 }

success: function(response) {
          var objResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
        if (objResponse.PreviousQueryString != "") {
           alert(objResponse.PreviousQueryString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Response is not in JSON data, it is an entire view

Comment: Form2 will be an MVC view (.cshtml file) and post action itself will call it